# What is the intuition behind mapping one range of numbers onto another range?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have a range $x \to y$ and I want to map it to $x' \to y'$, what is the logic behind the mapping process? I found the formula online as:

$$R = (y' - x') / (y - x)$$

$$\text{output} = (\text{input} - x) * R + x'$$

I understand that $R$ is the ratio of both ranges, but I don't understand the second part where we subtract $x$ from the input? Why do we do this, I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Let $t \in [x,y]$ and look for a linear function $f(t)=at+b$ to map it to a $t' \in [x',y']$. Write the conditions $f(x)=x', f(y)=y'$ and solve the system for $a,b$.

Comment: Try and draw some images of the sets, it can often help. Subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are often depicted on a number line.

Comment: Also try and learn some typesetting as it will often help to get better response.

Comment: @mathreadler where may I go to find documentation on types of stuff I can use to make my equations look more pretty?

Comment: Here is one quicky on the site: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  then mathjax is quite similar to LaTeX which is a large typesetting language which you may want to learn if you want to write longer more serious stuff like on paper or book form.

Comment: thank you, this will be very handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the hint given by the comments, I managed to derive the equation by using the point slope formula. I found the slope with the two points as described by dxiv and the rest smoothly followed.

EDIT:

The real confusion was actually the part where I didn't realize that the range could be thought of as being

$$f(a) = a'$$
$$f(b) = b'$$

Once I realized this it all came together and made more sense. Nothing really beats understanding how to derive the formula instead of just remembering it.

Comment: `Nothing really beats understanding how to derive the formula instead of just remembering it.` +1 for this alone.